# Button name is not displayed in blue color

Tags: android, button, android-intent

In eclipse IDE,the button name shown in black itself and it is not displaying any error,

Here is my code :

```
 Button b1;
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondactivity.class);
               startActivity(i);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
button.setTextColor(getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Or in XML

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybtn" 
        android:text="text textx "  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />
```